# Prefix protobuf message with signed 4 byte int

Tags: javascript, websocket, protocol-buffers, protobuf.js

I am working with a Websocket API which I send protobuf objects to.

The documentation says:

> Server uses Big Endian format for binary data.
> Messages sent back and forth require a signed 4 byte int of the message size, prefixed to the message

So the payload should be a 4 byte int which contains the message size, followed by the message itself.

I set the message like this:

```
const message = req.serializeBinary();
```

How would I prefix a `signed 4 byte int` that contains the message size to this?

Note: `console.log(message)` prints the following to the console:

```
jspb.BinaryReader {decoder_: j…b.BinaryDecoder, fieldCursor_: 0, nextField_: -1, nextWireType_: -1, error_: false, …}
decoder_: jspb.BinaryDecoder
bytes_: Uint8Array(78) [0, 0, 0, 74, 152, 182, 75, 75, 242, 233, 64, 4, 49, 48, 53, 57, 242, 233, 64, 35, 77, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 32, 108, 101, 110, 103, 116, 104, 32, 114, 101, 99, 101, 105, 118, 101, 100, 32, 105, 115, 32, 105, 110, 118, 97, 108, 105, 100, 46, 194, 233, 64, 19, 82, 105, 116, 104, 109, 105, 99, 32, 83, 121, 115, 116, 101, 109, 32, 73, 110, 102, 111]
cursor_: 78
end_: 78
error_: false
start_: 0
__proto__: Object
error_: false
fieldCursor_: 55
nextField_: 132760
nextWireType_: 2
readCallbacks_: null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used google's protocol buffers library, only protobuf.js (https://github.com/protobufjs), but I assume we can work based on your object, since all we need is in message.bytes_

```
bl = message.bytes_.length;
msg = new Uint8Array(bl+4);
msg.set([(bl&0xff000000)>>24,(bl&0xff0000)>>16,(bl&0xff00)>>8,(bl&0xff)]);
msg.set(message.bytes_,4);
yourwebsocketobject.send(msg); // or maybe msg.buffer?
```

You will probably get better answers, but this may eventually work.

Comment: Are you sure the `msg.set` line is correct? When I isolate that and hard code the value of `bl` to 4, the bytes are all zeros... just as they are when I try to use the real message length.

Comment: which line does not work for you, the first msg.set or the second? for me it all works both on node and firefox, which environment are you in?

Comment: Here's an example where `87` is being encoded to `[0, 0, 0, 7]` when isolating the code for the first 4 bytes: https://pastebin.com/1ERyYaPK

Comment: oops! i am sorry. i was using the bit mask wrongly, 0xf instead of 0xff.  i didn't see this before because i tested with values lower than 16. thanks for telling me. it is fixed now.

Comment: That did it. Thank you!